# Cannot open expo client version 2.16.1 in iOS simulator

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I have updated expo client in my iOS simulator(iOS13.3) and I am using Xcode 11.3.1.My mac os version is 10.15.3. When I tried to open my expo client then it will showing popup message like this

[image]

How can resolve the issue? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This issue fixed by resolving my xcode version updated to 11.7